# How to configure docker-compose.yml to invalidate Docker cache based on a certain file checksum

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I need to configure docker-compose.yml in a way that will invalidate the local image's docker cache, based on a certain file's checksum.

If it's not possible, I'd like to be able to somehow version the docker-compose.yml or Dockerfile, so that it would rebuild the Docker image of a specific service. I'd want to avoid pushing images to DockerHub. Unless it's an absolute the only solution.

At all costs, I want to avoid bash scripts and in general, writing imperative logic. I'm also not interested in CLI solutions, like passing additional flags to `docker-compose up` command.

Context:
We use docker-compose during the development of our application.
Our app has also a Dockerfile for building the app localy. We don't push docker images into DockerHub, we just have Dockerfile locally and in docker-compose.yml we declare the sourcecode and package.json (a file that for nodeJS applications use to declare dependencies) as volumes. Now sometimes, we modify the package.json, and `docker-compose up` throws an error, because the image is already built locally and the previous built doesn't contain the new dependencies. I'd want to be able to tell docker-compose.yml to automatically build a new image if there have been any changes to package.json file since we pull dependencies during the build stage.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    web:
        build:
            context: .
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        command: npx nodemon -L app.js
        volumes:
            - ./app:/usr/src/app
            - /usr/src/app/node_modules
        env_file: 
            - .env
        depends_on:
            - mongo
        
    mongo:
        image: mongo:latest
        container_name: mongo_db
        volumes:
            - ./config/init.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sh
            - ./config/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf
            - ./logs:/var/log/mongodb/
            - ./db:/data/db
        env_file:
            - .env
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"
        restart: on-failure:5
        command: ["mongod", "-f", "/etc/mongod.conf"]

volumes:
    db-data:
    mongo-config:
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14.15.1

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

#Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["node", "/app/app.js"]
```

Comment: Wouldn't `docker-compose build && docker-compose up --force-recreate` suffice? BTW, this should rebuild the image while the previous version is still running, to reduce the offline time as much as possible… (unlike `docker-compose up --build` at first sight)

Comment: The standard Dockerfile [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) directive does exactly what you describe.  I think your problem isn't anything related to the build cache; it's that you've told Docker the `node_modules` directory is user data that must not be updated.  I'd recommend deleting the `volumes:` entirely, and making sure to `COPY` the application code in your Dockerfile.  You can use a host `node` with the container MongoDB for day-to-day development.

Comment: @ErikMD Please, I've explicitly stated that I don't seek CLI solutions.

Comment: @DavidMaze wouldn't I lose hot reload capabilities if I'd do that? I use a watcher inside docker image that reloads the app when the code changes, if I'll remove source code from volumes, then I will lose the capability of seeing the changes immediately after introducing changes during development, which is a hindrance.

Comment: Nevermind, I misread. @DavidMaze I've thought it would be possible while preserving dockerization (I'm speaking about day to day development). I'll treat it as a solution, but not ideal one.